# Lenovo ThinkPad400s screen cracked. Warranty expired. What are my options?

Tags: lenovo-laptop

While adjusting screen on my laptop it cracked.  I bought it almost two years ago and my warranty is expired. What are my options?

Comment: I bought Lenovo because I heard how sturdy and tough they were and it looks like they are not. I'm not going to be buying a lenovo anytime soon if ever again.

Comment: My experience with ThinkPads is that they'll break into small pieces at the slightest caress. (Exaggeration. But I think the low-end ones are surely the opposite of sturdy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had success buying  replacements from e-bay and other online sellers.  There are usually good online guides for replacement.  It may take some small screw and fastner drivers as well.  Patience is important.  One seller offered a free printout of the manual pages needed for the swap.  Naturally you will need to weigh the cost against a replacement system.

Have to say we have several older T30 series and even A31s that are still going and have been used in factories and by many different people. Dells and Toshibas from same era are not faring as well. Nearly all similar Toshibas are damaged beyond repair.

Comment: +1 for ebay replacements, its cheap and easy to do especially on lenovo's/ibm. Reliability really depends on the model line, The T40's for instance were solid machines, but suffered from extreme motherboard flex that would slowly kill them for 6 months (the problem started usually 3-4 years down the line)

Comment: Good news about this is there should be a plethora of systems that are broken and failed but still have functioning screens. A screen swap is relatively easy relative to many laptop repairs.